# Can you say "ending result"?

Tags: expressions

Is it correct to say "ending result" instead of "end result"? 
For example: "Here it is the ending result of my project" is this correct?

Comment: "Result" typically implies an end already; you could just as well leave it out and say "Here is the result of my project." Also: leave out the word "it", it is not needed.

Answer (score 1):

No, 'ending result' doesn't work in English - but 'final result' would be fine, and even, sounds good!